# Read xml namespace from root element c#

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I have an xml that looks like this:

```
<imp:root xmlns:imp="http://......" xmlns="http://........">
   <imp:doc>blabla</imp:doc>
   ....
</imp:root>
```

I'm having trouble getting the namespace imp from the root when the root uses that namespace.

- Is it possible to define an xml like this with the root element using an namespace.
- How do I parse this in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [XNamespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to access those xml elements with namespace..

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(path);
XNamespace imp="http://";
```

Now to access root element

```
doc.Element(imp+"root");
```

---

Alternatively you can avoid using namespace using [LocalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.localname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
 doc.Elements.Single(x=>x.Name.LocalName=="root");
```